# MySQL: list users which have been granted EXECUTE permission on a given procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions, information-schema

I would like to audit my database to check which users have been granted individual EXECUTE permission to which procedure.

I would like to use this information to be able to save GRANTs when changing (DROP+CREATE) the definition of some procedure in order to restore them after.

How can I query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA or MYSQL schemas to retrieve that information?

**Update** I'm interested in a solution working on MySQL 5.6+.

For granular security, users of our datase are not granted an EXECUTE permission on the whole schema but on specific stored procedures. Answers on schema-level permissions are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging in the `mysql` schema (`USE mysql; SHOW TABLES;`) I found the `procs_priv` table that contains the information I need:

```
SELECT Routine_type, Routine_name, User, Host
FROM mysql.procs_priv
WHERE Db = DATABASE()
AND Proc_priv = 'Execute';
```

Comment: I believe that stores the results of `GRANT EXECUTE, ... ON FUNCTION (or proc) dbname.functionname TO user@host;` -- Note that that is one user at a time.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, that's the point of my question.

Answer (score 0):

This script executes and shows all privileges associated for account.

`SHOW GRANTS FOR 'antonio'@'antonio@gmail.com';`

Comment: This is not a good answer to the question. Assume there are 2,000 users are you going to do this 2,000 times?

Answer (score 0):

What version of MySQL?

(At least) before 8.0, this will list users that have "Execute" privilege in all databases:

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE Execute_priv = 'Y';
```

This will say which ones have permission in a particular `my_db`:

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE Execute_priv = 'Y' AND db = "my_db";
```

(The following probably works in all recent versions:)

But also keep in mind the distinction between these:

```
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
```

See also:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_SCHEMA,  -- (database)
       ROUTINE_NAME,
       ROUTINE_TYPE,    -- PROCEDURE or FUNCTION
       DEFINER,         -- eg, "root@localhost"
       SECURITY_TYPE    -- INVOKER or DEFINER
    FROM information_schema.ROUTINES;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. My question is about specific right granted on specific stored procedures, not about general permission on a whole schema.

Comment: @dolmen - There seem to be two ways to GRANT execute permission to a user -- My Answer covers the `GRANT EXECUTE ON db.* TO user@host` -- without specifying specific functions/procs.

Comment: Exactly. That's why it doesn't answer my question.